# Не работают команды линукс на удаленной машине

Tags: linux, ssh

Подключаюсь на другую машину под линукс через `ssh` и обнаруживаю, что команды линукс не работают.

С чем это может быть связано?

```
 a.khapkin@mtpro32:~>
 [11:42:27]
 a.khapkin@mtpro32:~>
 [11:42:27]
 a.khapkin@mtpro32:~>ls
 -bash: ls: command not found
 [11:42:28]
 a.khapkin@mtpro32:~>clear
 -bash: clear: command not found
 [11:42:31]
 a.khapkin@mtpro32:~>mkdir 1
 -bash: mkdir: command not found
 [11:42:34]
 a.khapkin@mtpro32:~>
 [11:42:35]
 a.khapkin@mtpro32:~>
```

При этом окружение питона включается нормально.

Comment: `/usr/bin/ls` ?

Comment: распечатайте `echo $PATH`

Comment: Выдал такое на $PATH:/home/a.khapkin/anaconda3/bin:usr/bin/local

Comment: /usr/bin/ls - пишет что нет такого вообще

Comment: Видимо там busybox нету.

Comment: */bin/ls*, во-первых, а во-вторых, это похоже на окружение удалённой установки CentOS или подобного. У вас точно система установлена там? (Кстати, это же VPS, правильно?) Python работает, потому что установщик RedHat  написан на python.

Comment: Причём тут busybox?

Comment: Да, когда я  ввожу bin/ls он работает, но напрмер как я понял команды clear в этой папке нет. Да, это виртуальный выделенный сервер по сути. Есть уже идеи, что может быть не так, кроме моих рук?)

Comment: Он не установлен полностью,)